# XMonad windows thumb overview

Tags: xmonad

Is there a possibility to get a overview of the present windows similar to other window managers where I can press Shift-TAB and get a overview with thumbnails of the present windows and can select one?

Comment: `rofi` might be useful application to achieve this.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Started ```rofi``` but ```rofi``` is showing a empty windows list when running under XMonad.

Comment: append: I meant ```rofi -show window``` is showing an empty windows list. But this link seems promising: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238674

Comment: Sounds like you may need the `XMonad.Config.Desktop` from xmonad-contrib.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski:  I'm using ```XMonad.Config.Gnome``` that imports ```XMonad.Config.Desktop```.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: I think I got it work. https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/xmonad/2014-February/014010.html. pointed it out: Had to chain ```ewmhDesktopsEventHook```, ```ewmhDesktopsStartup``` and ```ewmhDesktopsLogHook``` to the config hooks of my setup. Now "rofi -show window" shows the window names.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski : Thanks for the rofi tip, I posted a desc on howto set it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ChrisStryczynski pointed out `rofi`  can be used. To get `rofi -show windows` work  `wmhDesktopsEventHook`, `ewmhDesktopsStartup` and `ewmhDesktopsLogHook` from  `XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops` need to be added with `<+>` to the respective hooks (i.e. [example](https://github.com/eiselekd/dotfiles/blob/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs)):

`rofi -show windows` in action runing in XMonad:

[image]

Comment: Just a tip you can use `rofi -show-icons` to have icons show up.

Comment: On ubuntu (20.04) you may use `rofi -show window` (dropping the trailing "s"). Haven't checked on arch yet, though.